# Grpc Authentication Flow

Tags: c#, authentication, server, grpc

I implemented Google Sign-In in an Android App and in a C# backend I was able to implement [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access#enable_server-side_api_access_for_your_app) flow. However I'm doing this within a special sign-in call.

I'm wondering what the expected flow on the server-side is (in C#). Do I better use an interceptor? Finally I need to be able to access authentication data in any subsequent calls of the same client. How do I put it into the ServerCallContext? I haven't found any good C# examples on how to do this.

BR,
Daniel

Comment: It's not obvious what you're trying achieve exactly, but it looks like once you exchange the auth code for the auth token, you should use the token to create a new client channel that uses the just-received auth token. The channel then need to be cached on the server side (just set a private field in your YourServiceImpl class that handles the calls from the android app?) and you use it for any calls initiated by the backend.  You can't really add custom data to "ServerCallContext" and it also doesn't seem that that's what you need in this case.

Comment: Basically I want to authenticate the "connection" and be able to relate all calls to its client caller on the server. What I'm doing now is to transfer the authCode with a "signIn" rpc call, get me the access token on the server and return it to the client. Then use an interceptor on the client to attach the token to every call. This enables me to identify the client in the server. However this feels like misusing the token as a session id.